# Взаимосвязь интерфейса, его разработки и кода программы

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, pyqt, ui

Сразу прошу прощения, если я путаю термины и названия.

В общем, у меня проблема: не до конца понимаю связь кода с интерфейсом. Я вроде понял, как пользоваться *TKinter'ом*, но в какой-то момент подумал "Ведь должны быть более простые способы реализации интерфейса и к тому же, более привлекательного".

Нашел в сети приложения для разработки интерфейса, моем случае это *Pixate*. Открыл я его, понаставил пару объектов и... Все. Что дальше? Как использовать его в программе?

Прочитал что-то про конвертацию файла из `.ui` в `.py` в этой https://tproger.ru/translations/python-gui-pyqt/ статье, но здесь разобран случай использования *PtQt* и *Qt Designer*.

Получается, `Qt Designer + PtQt = TKinter`? Но это значит, что *библиотека* имеет свою собственную *среду разработки UI*, привязанную к этой самой библиотеке? Тогда как использовать остальные программы по типу *Pixate*?

Итак, у меня есть код, но его длина почти 160 строк, поэтому покажу фрагмент.

```
stop_word='продолжить'
while stop_word!='выйти':
   if stop_word=='продолжить':        
       par_code_1=input("Введите первый родительский генетический код ")
       while len(par_code_1)%2!=0:         
           print('----ОШИБКА----')
           print('Длина кода не может быть нечетной')
           print()
           par_code_1=input("Введите первый родительский генетический код ")
       par_code_2=input("Введите второй родительский генетический код ")
       while len(par_code_2)%2!=0:
           print('----ОШИБКА----')
           print('Длина кода не может быть нечетной')
           print()
           par_code_2=input("Введите второй родительский генетический код ")
       if len(par_code_1)!=len(par_code_2):
           while len(par_code_1)!=len(par_code_2):
               print('----ОШИБКА----')
               print('Оба кода должны иметь одинаковую длину')
               print()
               par_code_1=(input("Введите первый родительский генетический код "))  
               while len(par_code_1)%2!=0:                                            
                   print('----ОШИБКА----')
                   print('Длина кода не может быть нечетной')
                   print()
                   par_code_1=input("Введите первый родительский генетический код ")
               par_code_2=input("Введите второй родительский генетический код ")
               while len(par_code_2)%2!=0:
                   print('----ОШИБКА----')
                   print('Длина кода не может быть нечетной')
                   print()
                   par_code_2=input("Введите второй родительский генетический код ")
       print(par_code_1)
       print(par_code_2)
```

Да, скорее всего, его можно сильно укоротить, только не бейте пожалуйста.

А вот по сути тот же самый фрагмент, но уже имеющий полноценное окно, поля и кнопки для работы (он не доработан, в нем есть ошибка, но, тем не менее, суть работы он отображает).

```
from tkinter import *

def clicked_1():
   global a1, status_1
   a1=input_window_1.get()
   status_1=0
   if len(a1)%2!=0:
       input_msg_1.configure(text='Введите первый родительский генетический код\n'
                             'Длина кода не может быть нечетной',fg='red')
   elif len(a1)%2==0:
       input_msg_1.configure(text='Введите первый родительский генетический код\n',
                             fg='black')
   status_1=1
   clicked_both()
   return(a1)
   
def clicked_2():
   global a2, status_2
   a2=input_window_2.get()
   status_2=0
   if len(a2)%2!=0:
       input_msg_2.configure(text='Введите второй родительский генетический код\n'
                             'Длина кода не может быть нечетной',fg='red')
   elif len(a2)%2==0:
       input_msg_2.configure(text='Введите второй родительский генетический код\n',
                             fg='black')
   status_2=1
   clicked_both()
   return(a2)
   
def clicked_both():
   if status_1==1 and status_2==1:
       if len(a1)!=len(a2):
           error_window_1.configure(text='Оба кода должны иметь одинаковую длину',
                                    fg='red')
       elif len(a1)==len(a2):
           error_window_1.configure(text='')
           

window = Tk()
window.title('Code Calculator')
window.geometry('600x400')

input_msg_1=Label(window,text='Введите первый родительский генетический код\n')
input_msg_1.grid(column=0,row=0)
input_msg_2=Label(window,text='Введите второй родительский генетический код\n')
input_msg_2.grid(column=0,row=1)

input_window_1=Entry(window,width=10)
input_window_1.grid(column=1,row=0)
input_window_2=Entry(window,width=10)
input_window_2.grid(column=1,row=1)

code_check_1=Button(window,text='Проверить',command=clicked_1)
code_check_1.grid(column=2,row=0)
code_check_2=Button(window,text='Проверить',command=clicked_2)
code_check_2.grid(column=2,row=1)

error_window_1=Label(window,text='')
error_window_1.grid(column=0,row=2)
```

В общем, *главный мой вопрос*: можно ли разработать для этого куска полноценный, не выглядящий как программа из 90-х, *интерфейс*, если это можно так назвать в данном случае, с помощью *Pixate* или подобных программ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(`Qt Designer + PtQt`) **!=** `TKinter`

Прежде чем запустить мой пример, убедитесь, что вы установили `PyQt5`

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

`PyQt` — реализация фреймворка `Qt` для языка `Python`.

В GUI с использованием ***PyQt5***, ваша задача может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, \
    QTextEdit, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QMessageBox, QApplication


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.errorFlag = False
        
        label_1 = QLabel("Введите первый <br>родительский генетический код.")
        label_2 = QLabel("Введите второй <br>родительский генетический код.")
        
        self.lineEdit_1 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit()
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        
        button = QPushButton("Click me")
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        
        grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(label_1, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit_1, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(label_2, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.textEdit, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(button, 3, 1)
        
    def onClicked(self):
        self.errorFlag = False
        text_1 = self.lineEdit_1.text()
        text_2 = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        if (len(text_1) % 2) != 0 or (not text_1):
            self.errorMsg("Длина первого кода не может быть нечетной.")
        if (len(text_2) % 2) != 0 or (not text_2):
            self.errorMsg("Длина второго кода не может быть нечетной.")
        if len(text_1) != len(text_2):
            self.errorMsg("Оба кода должны иметь одинаковую длину.") 

        if not self.errorFlag:
            self.run()        
            
            
    def errorMsg(self, text):
        msg = QMessageBox.information(
            self, 
            "Внимание!", 
            text
        )
        self.errorFlag = True        

    def run(self):
        self.textEdit.append("Контроль ввода кода - пройден. Делайте что-нибудь.")
       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]